# C# find JWT claim by key

Tags: c#, jwt

I am trying to find a JWT claim by its key. Unfortunately I don't know how to do so. This is what I have to convert my token into a JWT Token:

```
var jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(token);
// Access claims
var claims = jwtToken.Claims;
```

The variable claims is now a list and looks like this:

```
[0] -> {companyId: 1}
[1] -> {username: johndoe}
[2] -> {email: john@doe.com}
```

How would I search for the key "companyId" for example to get its value?

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
var username = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "username").Value;
```